# Exactly clone an object in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone

I tried to exactly clone an object in javascript. I know the following solution using jquery:

```
var newObject = jQuery.extend({}, oldObject);
// Or
var newObject = jQuery.extend(true, {}, oldObject);
```

but the problem with that is, that the objects type gets lost:

```
var MyClass = function(param1, param2) {
    alert(param1.a + param2.a);
};
var myObj = new MyClass({a: 1},{a: 2});
var myObjClone = jQuery.extend(true, {}, myObj);
alert(myObj instanceof MyClass);      // => true
alert(myObjClone instanceof MyClass); // => false
```

Is there any solution to get true on the second alert?

Comment: David, the difference to all the other clone questions is that I asked for how to preserve the objects type property.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

jQuery.extend is not expecting you to use the instanceof operator.  It is doing a gloriously complicated copy, and not a true clone.  Looping through the elements is not enough.  Also, calling the constructor isn't best cause you'll loose your arguments.  Try this:

```
var MyClass = function(param1, param2) {
    alert(param1.a + param2.a);
    this.p1 = param1;
    this.p2 = param2;
};

function Clone() { }
function clone(obj) {
    Clone.prototype = obj;
    return new Clone();
}

var myObj = new MyClass({a: 1},{a: 2});
var myObjClone = clone(myObj);
alert(myObj instanceof MyClass);      // => true
alert(myObjClone instanceof MyClass); // => true
console.log(myObj);       //note they are
console.log(myObjClone)   //exactly the same
```

Be aware that since your prototype now points back to the origional (myObj), any changes to myObj will reflect in myObjClone.  Javascript's prototypal inheritance is kinda tricky.  You need to be sure that your new object has the correct prototype, and hence the correct constructor.

Admitadly, Javascript makes my head hurt.  Still, I think I'm reading this right, from the [ECMAScript language spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm):

> 13.2.2 [[Construct]]
>   When the [[Construct]] internal method for a Function object F is called with a possibly empty list of arguments, the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Let obj be a newly created native ECMAScript object.
> 2. Set all the internal methods of obj as specified in 8.12.
> 3. Set the [[Class]] internal property of obj to "Object".
> 4. Set the [[Extensible]] internal property of obj to true.
> 5. Let proto be the value of calling the [[Get]] internal property of F with argument >"prototype".
> 6. If Type(proto) is Object, set the [[Prototype]] internal property of obj to proto.
> 7. If Type(proto) is not Object, set the [[Prototype]] internal property of obj to the >standard built-in Object prototype object as described in 15.2.4.
> 8. Let result be the result of calling the [[Call]] internal property of F, providing >obj as the this value and providing the argument list passed into [[Construct]] as args.
> 9. If Type(result) is Object then return result.
> 10. Return obj.

[This person](http://oranlooney.com/functional-javascript/) seems to understand the concept much better than I do.  K, I'm going back to java now where I swim more than I sink :) .

Comment: Thas's a very nice solution. Additionaly you could copy all properties of the clones prototype to the clone so changes to myObj will not reflect in myObjClone. But what happens if you call clone again on a different object, will the prototype of myObjClone be changed?

Comment: If you try "myNewObjClone = clone(myObj)", then no, you don't change the prototype of myObjClone.  The Clone object only lives inside the clone function, so you get a new one each time you call clone(obj).  That is an example of using closure to "hide" a variable, in this case, the object Clone.

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered using the clone [function suggested here](http://keithdevens.com/weblog/archive/2007/Jun/07/javascript.clone)?

```
function clone(obj){
    if(obj == null || typeof(obj) != 'object'){
        return obj;
    }

    var temp = new obj.constructor();
    for(var key in obj){
        temp[key] = clone(obj[key]);
    }
    return temp;
}

var MyClass = function(param1, param2) {};
var myObj = new MyClass(1,2);
var myObjClone = clone(myObj);
alert(myObj instanceof MyClass);      // => true
alert(myObjClone instanceof MyClass); // => true
```

Comment: That's a good start, but the clone fails if the constructor requires parameters: 
var MyClass = function(param1, param2) {alert(param1.test)};

Comment: Tom, where do you expect this `clone` function to get the expected arguments from? How is it to know?

Comment: @J-P - That's what my question is about. Is there a way to get an exact clone preserving the type information without knowing anything about the object to clone. I now assume it's impossible.

Answer (score 2):

After taking inspiration from some answers I've found on StackOverflow, I've come up with a function that is quite flexible, and still works when the object or any of its sub-objects has a constructor with required parameters (thanks to Object.create).

(Thanks to Justin McCandless this now supports cyclic references as well.)

```
//If Object.create isn't already defined, we just do the simple shim, without the second argument,
//since that's all we need here
var object_create = Object.create;
if (typeof object_create !== 'function') {
    object_create = function(o) {
        function F() {}
        F.prototype = o;
        return new F();
    };
}

/**
 * Deep copy an object (make copies of all its object properties, sub-properties, etc.)
 * An improved version of http://keithdevens.com/weblog/archive/2007/Jun/07/javascript.clone
 * that doesn't break if the constructor has required parameters
 * 
 * It also borrows some code from http://stackoverflow.com/a/11621004/560114
 */ 
function deepCopy(src, /* INTERNAL */ _visited, _copiesVisited) {
    if(src === null || typeof(src) !== 'object'){
        return src;
    }

    //Honor native/custom clone methods
    if(typeof src.clone == 'function'){
        return src.clone(true);
    }

    //Special cases:
    //Date
    if(src instanceof Date){
        return new Date(src.getTime());
    }
    //RegExp
    if(src instanceof RegExp){
        return new RegExp(src);
    }
    //DOM Element
    if(src.nodeType && typeof src.cloneNode == 'function'){
        return src.cloneNode(true);
    }

    // Initialize the visited objects arrays if needed.
    // This is used to detect cyclic references.
    if (_visited === undefined){
        _visited = [];
        _copiesVisited = [];
    }

    // Check if this object has already been visited
    var i, len = _visited.length;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        // If so, get the copy we already made
        if (src === _visited[i]) {
            return _copiesVisited[i];
        }
    }

    //Array
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(src) == '[object Array]') {
        //[].slice() by itself would soft clone
        var ret = src.slice();

        //add it to the visited array
        _visited.push(src);
        _copiesVisited.push(ret);

        var i = ret.length;
        while (i--) {
            ret[i] = deepCopy(ret[i], _visited, _copiesVisited);
        }
        return ret;
    }

    //If we've reached here, we have a regular object

    //make sure the returned object has the same prototype as the original
    var proto = (Object.getPrototypeOf ? Object.getPrototypeOf(src): src.__proto__);
    if (!proto) {
        proto = src.constructor.prototype; //this line would probably only be reached by very old browsers 
    }
    var dest = object_create(proto);

    //add this object to the visited array
    _visited.push(src);
    _copiesVisited.push(dest);

    for (var key in src) {
        //Note: this does NOT preserve ES5 property attributes like 'writable', 'enumerable', etc.
        //For an example of how this could be modified to do so, see the singleMixin() function
        dest[key] = deepCopy(src[key], _visited, _copiesVisited);
    }
    return dest;
}
```

This function is part of my [simpleOO](https://github.com/mbrowne/simpleoo.js) library; any bug fixes or enhancements will be made there (feel free to open an issue on github if you discover some bug).

- [Basic documentation](https://github.com/mbrowne/simpleoo.js/wiki/API#wiki-deepCopy)
- [Example](https://github.com/mbrowne/simpleoo.js/wiki/Additional-Examples#wiki-deepCopy)

Answer (score 1):

```
function clone( obj ) {  
    var target = new obj.constructor();  
    for ( var key in target ) { delete target[key]; }  
    return $.extend( true, target, obj );  
}
```

$.extend can't copy all the internal properties that are not visible (some are visible in firefox), but if `obj.constructor` is correct, and won't fault without args, the internal properties can be set with `new obj.constructor()`.  If you do inheritance with something like `Derived.prototype = new Base()`, you also would need to follow that with `Derived.prototype.constructor = Derived` to get the constructor right.

You could do `$.extend( true, new obj.constructor(), obj )`, but it's possible the constructor creates properties that were later deleted -- even if you could get the constructor args right -- that's why the properties have to be deleted before doing the extend.  It doesn't matter that the constructor args are wrong since the effects of the original constructor args -- plus everything else that has happened to the object since then -- are in the object we're cloning.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are passing in a new object to copy to '{}'.  This is why you lose your type.  I found that if you wrap the real object before passing it in and unwrap the copied object afterwards, extend will preserve the type as expected.

```
function clone(obj)
{
    var wrappedObj = { inner: obj };
    var newObject = jQuery.extend(true, {}, wrappedObj);
    newObject = newObject.inner;
    return newObject;
}
```

Comment: i think this is the best answer, thanx you rock MAN :)

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox you could write:

```
Object.prototype.clone = function() {
  return eval(uneval(this));
}
```

Can be used like:

```
object1 = object2.clone();
```

Answer was found here :[source](http://www.thespanner.co.uk/2008/04/10/javascript-cloning-objects/)

But it's just Firefox magic. Other browsers might crash here.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternate solution that doesn't exactly copy or clone anything, but should give the desired results.

```
var myObj = new MyClass({a: 1},{a: 2});
var myObjCreator = MyClass.bind(this, {a: 1},{a: 2});
var myObjClone = new myObjCreator();
```

This uses Javascript's `bind` function to create an object that automatically passes in the given parameters to the MyClass constructor.

I had similar requirements as the OP and this worked for me so I thought I'd post it, though I realize some people might need a true deep copy on a modified object and this won't fit the bill.